# Ubuntu being... not too fast?

Tags: 12.04, unity, performance

Yeah I know there is enough of similar questions already - why ubuntu is slow and blah blah.

But, seriously. I have pretty ok-ish specs - desktop PC with Intel i3 and 4 GB ram. When I'm on Windows I run a lot of programs - IDE, Skype, Photoshop and a couple of browsers with lots of tabs open and never run into performance issues. Alt+Tab`ing between windows is smooth and multitasking is awesome.

But then I run Ubuntu and get none of this. Alt+tab takes a second to appear on the screen, programs launch a bit slow for the first time, faster afterwards though. Switching between open programs feels slow. Not too slow, but not fast either, while I have enough specs to have it fast. I have read a bunch of guides on how to improve the overall performance (like switching to old Unity 2D and using "preload" tool), tried some of it but never achieved similar multitasking performance comparing to Windows.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just how Ubuntu is? I'm a web-developer and I really want to switch to UNIX from Windows, but I'm really used to having tons of programs being open and comfortably switching between them and multitask and unfortunately I couldn't achieve this with Ubuntu.

**Quick edit**:

I'm dualbooting with Windows and Ubuntu using Grub.

I didn't use Wubi to install Ubuntu.

I have an Intel HD Graphics adapter, could this be a problem?

My swap is 4 GB, and I tried playing around with `swappiness`, didn't improve the speed much

Answer (score 0):

Please notice your swap partition is too big an probably will never be used to the limit. Refer to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/5841/how-much-swap-space-on-a-high-memory-system) post to understand why.